# Java - Scanner Delimiter - 'Dangling meta character '+' near index 0'

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

I'm trying to read out a file.

This file has multiple attributes of a specific Object, which is not relevant right now.

But these attributes are seperated with a '+' sign.

Now, when I try to read them out and use a Delimiter for the +, I get the error: `Dangling meta character '+' near index 0`

Note: the file starts with a '1' (id of object in database) and not with a '+'

This is the code I have been using:

```
public void doImport() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    file = new File(document);
    Scanner fileIn = new Scanner(file);

    while(fileIn.hasNextLine()){

        //reading a single line of the file
        String line = fileIn.nextLine();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(line);

        //setting the delimiter
        scan.useDelimiter("+");

        while(scan.hasNext()){
            //printing contents, split by a +
            System.out.println(scan.next());
        }

        String string = fileIn.nextLine();
        System.out.println(string);
    }
    fileIn.close();
}
```

The Content of the File: [image: fileContent]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Delimiter expects a regex pattern, so in this case you should use:
`scan.useDelimiter("\\+");`

The + sign in regex means you want 1 or more matches e.g. `[a-z]+` meaning one or more letters from a to z.